# How do I search for a specific email subject using python and a wildcard?

Tags: python, outlook, wildcard, python-re

I want to use the below code to search for all emails that came into "MyInbox" today, with a subject beginning with "Company UK Cash Movement...". Usually the emails will come in with that exact subject but the ending can change. In VBA i would use a wildcard *, but I'm unsure how to implement this in python.

Ive also not yet figured out how to only search the emails received today.

```
import win32com.client
import datetime
import re
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
folder = outlook.Folders("MyInbox")
inbox = folder.Folders.Item("Inbox")

messages = inbox.Items
messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)

for message in messages:
    if message.subject == 'Company UK Cash Movement.+':
        print("Found message")
    else:
        print("not found")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `.startswith()`:

```py
import win32com.client
import datetime
import re
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
folder = outlook.Folders("MyInbox")
inbox = folder.Folders.Item("Inbox")

messages = inbox.Items
messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)

for message in messages:
    if message.subject.startswith('Company UK Cash Movement'):
        print("Found message")
    else:
        print("not found")
```

Comment: Never loop through all messages in a folder. You wouldn't execute a SELECT statement in SQL without a WHERE clause, would you?

Answer (score 1):

Don't loop though all items in a folder. use `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict`.

You can pass the following query to Items.Restrict (it will return another Items collection with the marches).

You can create a query on the PR_NORMALIZED_SUBJECT property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1D001F`). Note that a restriction on Subject won't work since it is not indexed (only normalized subject is).

```
set matches = inbox.Items.Restrict("@SQL=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1D001F"" like '%Company UK Cash Movement%' ")
MsgBox matches.Count
```